# Como fazer uma divisão ou subtração exata/precisa, no PHP

Tags: php, matemática

Estou tendo dificuldades para fazer um cálculo exato no PHP, observe.

```
$selic = 0,96;
$ipca  = 0,42;
bcscale(10);
$sub = bcsub($selic, $ipca);   //Retona: 0.54000000
// ou
$sub = $selic - $ipca;         //Retorna: 0.54
```

O resultado exato para essa fórmula `no Excel` é: 0,54316901573592300

Isso valé para subtração, adição, divisão e multiplicação, alguém pode me ajudar?

**Edição**
Foi mal aí, o erro é no Excel, não com o PHP. Não estou nem um pouco habituado com ele. Mas obrigado a todos.

Comment: O problema esta no `$selic` e no `$ipca`, oras bolas,`0.96 - 0.46` da exatamente `0.54`

Comment: olha amigo 0,96 - 0,42 = 0,54 a sua formula no excel deve estar errada

Comment: Veja la no seu arquivo excel, que o valor de ipca e selic não é exatamente esses, estenda as casas apos a virgula :)

Comment: Eu vou pegar esses dados dinamicamentes de uam API, e essa api só retorna 2 casas depois da virgula

Comment: Ai não ha o que fazer, infelizmente

Comment: `$selic = 0.96013899947120500`.
`$ipca = 0.41696998373528200` .
resultado da subtração: `0.54316901573592300`.

Agora `0.96 - 0.46 = 0.54`

Comment: Então o meu problema vai ser com a API ou com o EXCEL? Qual eu devo confiar?

Comment: Ou procurar um ws que informe o valor com mais casas decimais, se quiser bater o excel com o resultado no seu calculo

Comment: Ixi, agora onde eu vou encontrar um WS do banco central, essa minha eu peguei do `portal de dados abertos do brasil`

Comment: @bfavaretto O excel do rapaz: https://onedrive.live.com/edit.aspx?cid=998af8ca813c01c8&page=view&resid=998AF8CA813C01C8!176&parId=998AF8CA813C01C8!175&authkey=!AA3V8edDxxIfbZo&app=Excel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Corrigindo o seu exemplo, o php não vai interpretar essas "virgulas" tem que ser ponto, e tem que estar entre aspas se for usar transformação de string, ou sem aspas se for numerico mesmo, mas igual terá que trocar virgula por ponto.

```
<?php
$selic = "0.96";
$ipca  = "0.42";
bcscale(10);
echo bcsub($selic, $ipca);   //Retona: 0.54000000
echo "<br>";// ou
echo ($selic - $ipca);         //Retorna: 0.54


$selic = "0.96013899947120500";
$ipca  = "0.41696998373528200";
bcscale(10);
echo bcsub($selic, $ipca,17);   //Retona: 0.54316901573592300
echo "<br>";// ou
echo ($selic - $ipca);         //Retorna: 0.54316901573592
```

Atualizado conforme comentários

Comment: Eu sei, foi um erro meu, eu não copiei este código eu fiz agora na hora, esses dados (ipca e selic) eu vou pegar de uma API, e ela só tem 2 casas após a vírgual entende? Queria ser o mais exato nas fórmulas o possível!

Comment: Bom ta explicado que você não tem problema no PHP, essa parte esta certinha conforme exemplo basta passar um terceiro parametro no bcsub(), terá que tratar os dados de entrada antes de fazer o calculo